# Usage of dinosaurs in war

Tags: warfare

In the story, humans have found a way to revive any dinosaur, no matter how complex the dinosaur may be. They are also able to cause mutations which can greatly increase or decrease the potential of that dinosaur. I'm just wondering what dinosaurs would be best for the army, one for air, one for land and one for sea. If necessary, what mutations would be needed to improve that dinosaur.

Comment: Who are the dinosaurs fighting? Trogs with rocks? Medieval Knights? Fighter Jets? Space aliens? Nanomachine plagues?

Comment: Why not two or three or more each for air, land and sea… or do all armies use one vehicle, all air-forces one plane and all navies one ship?

If you can revive any and all dinosaurs and mutate them any way you like, what could anyone else contribute but… uh… all the actual work?

Comment: Best is a highly subjective and context dependent metric. Without knowing a specific military's specific strategic, and political goals how do you expect us to know what would be best for them. This is compounded for militaries in particular since by their nature they exist to oppose other nation's militaries. The choices of one military will have an impact on other militaries decisions. Given all this complexity and it's dependence on in world decisions this question is too broad and too opinion based to be suitable for this site.

Comment: Here are real examples of usage of dinosaurs in wars: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDwsnpo066g&ab_channel=TheHistoryGuy%3AHistoryDeservestoBeRemembered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They would be immensely powerful.

A TL,DR:

You can build biological drones for a large variety of purposes. They can do more complex stuff than any non-flying drone we have currently and some of the same stuff that flying drones can do. Just delivering grenades with small fliers is a win. These Dino’s also dont require the immensely complex and rare materials consuming production processes. This at the very least is a good addition for a disposable military use.

Long version:

Sure a .50cal might be able to harm most larger animals where normal small arms are a match for most smaller dino’s you can throw at it, but thats not the point. This isnt a 1v1 where the normal humans are always in a perfect position. This is a war.

You get at least two types of dino’s in your army: simple Dino’s with quick growth periods and complex Dino’s that can perform more complex or demanding tasks.

For example lets say you build a cat-sized Dino with some nasty claws and mouth, possibly a mouth like the snapping turtle for extra bite. Their size and relative simplicity means you can breed them quickly and en masse possibly to adults within months to a year for a steady stream of them. Their primary goal is to swarm at a group of soldiers and hang on to them while biting any place where they dont encounter an armor plate. This saps a lot of ammunition trying to stop them as they are small but fast targets, and you will naturally be attacking with regular soldiers at the same time! Even if your opponent wears full body armor and is impervious to their bites and claws, the simple fact that there’s now several kilo’s worth of multiple dinosaurs climbing over you is going to frustrate any action you take. Better yet: every 10th mini Dino carries a grenade and its in its nature to make a motion to pull the pin if it reaches a target.

More complex dino’s are used for specific tasks. For example a Dino designed to dig trenches and fortify them would be an immense boon to soldiers since digging trenches is incredibly hard work. Larger Dino’s could be bred for carrying a lot of weight. That can be simple supplies but also armor so you can make moving pieces of cover able to handle small-arms or function as a Heavy Machine Gun carrier. Having swarms of large dog or human sized Dino’s to run headlong into a trench would also be useful. Yes trenches and machine guns are well capable of handling such swarms, but if you add in regular troops and those tiny Dino’s you can make it a lot easier to approach. And the added bonus is that you dont care about the Dino losses, so if a mere dozen reach the lines they have already served their purpose as distractions and bullet sponges. If they wound or kill anything there, or perhaps commit sabotage by climbing into artillery tubes and the like, you have a bonus.

Flying troops would do similar stuff, small fliers are perfect to swarm over infantry, including the drivers of tanks when they take a rest. Larger fliers are hopefully too cheap to use missiles on so they can try to pass over low defended enemy lines and then harass supply lines and HQ’s. Similarly aquatic Dino’s would help river crossings and the like.

This is ofcourse assuming current tech holds. But again: biological drones! They will have their uses.

Comment: I think a lot would come down to how easy they are to domesticate and train. Humans didn't always have a thing against using animals in war, but "trained battle cats" (or the favorite "bear cavalry" meme) never seemed to catch on. But for story purposes I guess we can just use the old "turns out, dinosaurs are ideal war animals". Who's to say they aren't!

Comment: @JamieB I would assume domestication isnt a problem. OP lets us add mutations to increase potential, and altering the mind of the animals would be top of that list. So going for traits that encourage domestication and trainability before altering anything else. That would mean social structures and lowered fear response to certain stimulants (like Dogs) to facilitate better animalistic mindsets for war. And if you have the ability also reflexive responses, like the “pull grenade pin” response I pointed out or just hanging on while biting anything not too hard.

Answer (score 6):

**Marginally more useful than mammals, maybe.**

You mentioned the ability to induce mutations. Assume they can do so in a directed manner. (Which would be an awesome bioscience achievement, even in dogs or horses.) Consider where the military uses animals, today.

- [Military working dogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogs_in_warfare)
  Those are relatively useful and common. Come up with a dinosaur that is loyal, obedient, and *very* good at smelling things. Another breed, or the same, is loyal, obedient, and willing to attack (and to stop) on command.
  For general purposes, assault rifles are better than assault dinos. But in some situations, like crowd control or searching cramped quarters, a dino may be useful.
- Mounted infantry
  There are a *few* instances where horses and mules are better [transports](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einsatz-_und_Ausbildungszentrum_f%C3%BCr_Tragtierwesen_230) than helicopters or all-terrain vehicles. Mostly in mountains, perhaps also in jungles. The infantry would not fight from the dino, it would travel on it.

And one more option, based on the fact that the dinosaurs are *not* part of the ecosystem as we know it.

- Ecological sabotage
  Introduce a fast-breeding, destructive dino in enemy territory as an invasive species. This might go as far as attacking humans with acid spittle, or whatever.

Comment: Jurassic park was 100% wrong about the dilophosaurus; it did NOT spit acid and as far as we know lacked a head frill. Okay, so maybe these people are tweaking the dinosaurs to “improve” them, but I’d just like to point this out. Sorry, this has been driving me nuts for a while, and not just on this forum.

Comment: @user98816 Yeah Stevie Spielberg is known for taking liberties with his dinos, among other things. The Animaniacs is riddled with this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 5):

None.

I like the idea of riding into Battle on an Armoured Triceratops as much as the next guy - but if your story has reached a level of technology that is capable of resurrecting extinct species, then it's going to be more advanced than the tech of today.

On Land, a Dinosaur as a Shock-troop might have some advantage - however large Calibre Weapons (.50 cal and above) and Anti-Tank systems would make very short work of a Dinosaur - a Tank would absolutely shred a Dino.

Same with the Air and the Sea.

The other issue is one of training - Lizards are not highly social Pack Mammals, so whilst in modern militaries we see the Military K9 units (Goodest bois), this is mainly because they can be trained to do a certain job.

Lizards are generally not trainable, which severely limits their combat applications.

Even if we assume that the means of resurrection is magical and not technology based and the people you are facing still use Sword, shield and armour - the ability to train a Dinosaur (although if we're using Magic - sod it - we can use it for that too!) is the biggest hinderance.

A T-Rex would be excellent against peasants and lightly armed medieval troops, but then it would also be excellent against yours....

And unable to tell the difference.

Comment: Many dinosaurs, such as raptors and dromaeosaurs, were pack hunters, and so would have had to cooperate and learn from each other. These you could almost certainly train; like big, toothy, birdlike dogs.

Comment: @user98816 you can teach a Raven and Ara to talk and solve puzzles. Larger Dinosaurs like Utah Raptors and bigger variants would be able to complete complex tasks and do things like scout. Small Dino’s the size of Ravens could use lasers and other things to paint targets, if not fly over an area and scout using a small camera or similar. They would be biological drones more advanced than what we can build today (of that size).

Comment: Dinosaurs are no more "lizards" than birds are

Comment: Hmm. Tech advancements aren't tied together, I think. Advancing in fusion reactors doesn't imply any advancement in batteries, for example. I could actually see an argument that some society greatly advanced in "nature tech" and in doing so, largely eliminated the need to advance in other areas. Developing the airplane wasn't as important with armies of trained flying dinosaurs that could deliver bombs, etc. Might be interesting to imagine a big alternate world that diverged into "nature tech" starting in like the late 1800s. (There is probably an anime about this.)

Comment: @JamieB - Interesting notion - and I see your point that certain technological leaps shouldn't be linked - however, I disagree - firstly that as a problem is solved for one bit of tech, either the solution or the process of solving it can be applied to other areas. Also Birds of a Feather flock together - really smart and creative types tend work together - so advances in one field drive advances in others.